# Correct way of destructing nodes in a binary tree (c++)

Tags: c++

I defined a binary node class in c++.
Now, I'm tryin to implement the destructor of the binary node, which basically should just free the heap space I allocated to its descendants.

So here's what I have done:

```
virtual ~BinaryNode(){
    freeSpace(left);
    freeSpace(right);
}
```

where `freeSpace(Node* node)` is a private auxiliary function I want to implement in the class.

My question is about 2 options:

```
void freeSpace(Node* curr){                 //Option 1
    if(curr->left)
        freeSpace(curr->left);
    if(curr->right)
        freeSpace(curr->right);
    delete curr;
}


    void freeSpace(Node* curr){                 //Option 2
        if(curr->left)
            left->freeSpace(curr->left);
        if(curr->right)
            right->freeSpace(curr->right);
        delete curr;
    }
```

What option would be the correct way to implement?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The function doesn't use `this` at all, so it really should be a static function anyway. But why not just `delete left; delete right;` in `~BinaryNode`, or better yet just use `std::unique_ptr<Node>`? Edit: I realize just now that there is a bug as well: `freeSpace` calls itself recursively *twice* per branch, because `delete curr` calls the destructor.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this instead:

```cpp
virtual ~BinaryNode() {
  delete left;
  delete right;
}
BinaryNode* root = new BinaryNode();
...
delete root;
```

Edit 1:
As `delete` calls the destructor of the object then deallocate the memory, you can utilise `delete` to recursively delete all of the nodes starting from the leaves. Thus, there is no need to create your own custom function to traverse the whole tree and call delete on each node.

Edit 2: Used @YvesDaoust suggestion and remove nullptr check

Comment: As `delete` on `null` is a no-op, `delete left; delete right;`  is enough.

Comment: @YvesDaoust What do you mean by no-op?

Comment: @DirichletIsaPartyPooper: check the description of `delete`.

Comment: @YvesDaust thanks for the suggestion. I updated my response with it.